# Bulk modify ActiveRecords based on condition in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model Posts with a column author_id ´, also I have a logged in user with a user_id

I am listing all Posts with:

```
posts = Post.all
```

In this post object I want to check for every post if the author_id equals the current user_id and if so, I want to add a new field to the object

```
is_author => true
```

I know I should do this in my model, but for a couple of reasons this won't be possible.

Another solution would be to loop through all posts and add the new field:

```
post_with_author = []

post.each do |post|
  add post to new array with new field
end
```

But this does not seem to be the best option.

Is there an oficial way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have author_id defined on Post, you could do

```
posts = Post.where(author_id: user_id).update_all(author: true)
```

This will construct and execute a single SQL update statement and will not create objects for each post. An important point to note here is that update_all skips all validations and callbacks.